# Beginner's Javascript Help, what statements to open a link if condition is true

Tags: javascript, web-applications, conditional-statements

I found this example: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/examples/detecting_internet_connection.htm
it will alert you if internet exists or not, what i would like to do is when condition is true, not to allert me that the connection exists, but to open a link.

```
<div id="mainContainer">    
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Check connection!</a>
</div>

var link = document.querySelector("#mainContainer a");
link.addEventListener("mousedown", checkConnection, false);

function checkConnection(e) {
    if (doesConnectionExist() == true) {
        alert("connection exists!");
    } else {
        alert("connection doesn't exist!");
    }
}

function doesConnectionExist() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = "http://www.kirupa.com/images/giant_cloud.png";
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);

    xhr.open('HEAD', file + "?rand=" + randomNum, false);

    try {
        xhr.send();

        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What i would like to do is in the:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Check connection!</a>
```

put a link like www.google.com and in the:

```
if (doesConnectionExist() == true) {
    alert("connection exists!");
```

Change the alert to something that will open the link www.google.com

This is going to be used in a webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (doesConnectionExist() == true) {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
}
```

Comment: thanks, but would it be possible to write the url in the a href and not in the  java, or for multiple links i need to make statements for each link?

Comment: Can you please explain it further.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (doesConnectionExist() == true) {
        window.open("https://www.google.com",'_blank');
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but would it be possible to write the url in the a href and not in the  java, or for multiple links i need to make statements for each link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

window.open("www.google.com");

I recommend visiting w3schools to see the available options
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp